# Dynamic buttons in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

I have a `link_to image_tag` that when clicked should pop up a modal to show a help screen.  The button code is:

`<%= link_to image_tag('help_sm.png'), '#', :id =>"btnShowHelp_"{current_step} %>`

where the `{current_step}` is the name of the step the user is on that corresponds to the help screen they are accessing.

I am getting a `SyntaxError` outputting the `current_step`.

Can someone help with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation in strings in ruby looks like this: `"#{var}"`, so you need to do this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('help_sm.png'), '#', :id =>"btnShowHelp_#{current_step}" %>
```

Note that you have to use double quotes(`"`) for string interpolation, if you use single quotes(`'`), it won't interpolate.

Comment: That fixed the problem, but led to another.  Now I have a NameError with this:

`<%= @project.current_step.capitalize %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to image_tag('help_sm.png'), '#', :id =>"btnShowHelp_#{current_step}" %>`

`current_step` works in the first part, but not the 2nd.  Ideas?

Comment: Fixed the NameError - `...#{@project.current_step}"`